# Update v-model from v-select if items are updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue Template:

```
<v-flex>
 <v-select
   label="Day"
   :items="daysInMonth"
   v-model="selectedDay"
  />
</v-flex>
<v-flex>
  <v-select
   label="Month"
   :items="months"
   v-model="selectedMonth"
  />
</v-flex>
<v-flex>
  <v-select
   label="Years"
   :items="years"
   v-model="selectedYear"
  />
</v-flex>
```

I am working on a date picker component with `v-select`. It's working fine but I am not understanding the behavior where I have a case for evaluating number of days in a month/year.

So `daysInMonth` is a computed property which will return number of days given `selectedMonth` & `selectedYear`.

Example case, `daysInMonth` have `[1, 2, 3, ..., 29]` and `selectedDay` is `29`, but right after new evaluation of `daysInMonth` i.e. say `[1, 2, 3, ..., 28]`, my `selectedDay` data value is preserved i.e. still showing `29` on Vue debug tools but not on UI.

What am I missing here? I want the value `selectedDay` to be updated if it doesn't have the value exist in items i.e. `daysInMonth`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `watch` on `daysInMonth`:

```
watch: {
  daysInMonth(val) {
    this.selectedDay = val.includes(this.selectedDay) ? this.selectedDay : 1;
  }
}
```

This will reset the `selectedDay` to 1 if it's not in the new `daysInMonth` array.